# Removing repeated ratios in Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a set (R,G,B)
i want to calculate the number of possibilities of each of RGB having the values from 0-255. in that case the permutation would be $256\times 256\times 256 = 16,777,216$.

but i need to remove those combinations of the numbers where i already have the set with similar ratios.

Eg if i have the set $(1,1,1)$ i have to ignore the sets $(2,2,2)$..to...$(255,255,255)$
likewise if i have the set $(1,2,3)$ then i have to ignore $(2,4,6)...(84,168,252)$

Is there any way or formula to get only unique ratios of numbers in a permutation

Answer (score 1):

Put another way, you want to count $\{(r, b, g) : 0 \leq r, b, g \leq 255, \gcd(r, b, g) = 1\}$. Actually, since $\gcd(0, 0, 0)=0$, you want 1 more than this count. In any case, it seems like a potential error-prone headache from a purely combinatorial perspective. Brute force is not hard, though. In Python:

```
from fractions import gcd
from itertools import product
1+sum(1 for rbg in product(range(256), repeat=3) if reduce(gcd, rbg) == 1)
```

produces 13,936,094 after several seconds.

**Edit:** I see your post was a bit vague about 0. You said 0-255 in one place but then used 256 in an example. The code above uses 0-255. If you want 1-256 instead, the answer ends up being 13,964,245